# i want to use card view to launch new activity in fragments .can anyone help me androidx

Tags: android, android-cardview

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    CardView bro,inv,cert,ban,card;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         galleryViewModel=
                ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( GalleryViewModel.class );
        View root = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false );
        CardView bro,inv,ban,card;
         cert = (CardView)root.findViewById( R.id.c1 );


public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.c1:
                i=new Intent( v.getContext(), hi.class);
                startActivity(i );
                break;
            case R.id.c2:
                i=new Intent( v.getContext(), hii.class);
                startActivity(i );
                break;
```

i have tried using cardview in fragments and i need to open new activity but when i am pressing in gallery fragment it is crashing

Comment: Please add clear details of your problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add relevant details.

Comment: Post your layout and your stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

After Adding getting your car with findViewbyid you need to set click action like below

```
cert = (CardView)root.findViewById( R.id.c1 );
cert.setOnClickListener(this) // --> Add this for your card 
// if you have any cards you must set setOnClickListener for them like above
```